# Page includes script from unauthenticated sources

Tags: bug, advertising, google-chrome, blocked, content

When i open the question [Entity framework, discriminator column, but no inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089331/entity-framework-discriminator-column-but-no-inheritance) chrome tells me that the page includes script from unauthenticated sources.

[image]

The Console of the Developer Tools contains the following entry:

> [blocked] The page at
>   'https://view.atdmt.com/MRT/iview/465522955/direct;wi.220;hi.250/01?click='
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   'http://cdn.doubleverify.com/dvtp_src.js?ctx=1842468&cmp=RUMTCRF00933MRT&sid…tadsrv=atdmt&crt=339566595&crtname=&chnl=&unit=&pid=&uid=&dvtagver=6.1.src': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

I´m not sure if it is a bug or something critical.

**Update:**

I think the problem is the Windows Azure advertisement. Cause when it is not displayed, chrome does not indicate unsecure content.

Comment: I opened this question and can't see a script you are talking about. Given that "tadsrv" part suggest ads and "atdmt" rings a "tracking cookie" bell to me, it's possible my proxy just got rid of that part for me. Or your system is compromised.

Comment: @Mołot I think its the ad. I´ve updated my question.

Comment: [Shahrooz Jefri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968030/shahrooz-jefri)'s avatar is being served from a non-HTTPS location: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvZK.jpg?s=32&g=1

Comment: @Jehof Are you still experiencing the issue? Our contact updated the tags and I'm not seeing the same error anymore.

Comment: @stevvve the issue seems to be gone. I have to hit F5 mutiple times to get the add displayed, but when it is displayed, Chrome does not indicate any unsecure content. So it should be fixed.

Comment: @Jehof excellent! Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: @stevvve why don't you ask for a diamond here so you can make edits without waiting for approval? With the new top bar review rate is really really slow as users just don't see there are suggested edits in the queue. (plus it might get rejected as spam if reviewer won't understand you're actually Stack Exchange employee)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Good call. Look --> there it is!

Comment: @stevvve congrats, missed that reply but noticed the diamond now!

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed the ad. While we request that all content served by ads is secure, it looks like this one is trying to load some non-secure content. We've asked them to fix this.

---

Update: Advertiser updated on their end, errors no longer present.

Comment: Microsoft. No surprise here.

Comment: The ad seems to be working now.

Comment: this problem strikes again for the Microsoft ad