# Google Shield on SO : Insecure Content

Tags: support, design, security

According to my other question, there appears to be a problem with Chrome and JavaScript.
I'm seeing a little shield in the address-bar, meaning there's [insecure content](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en) on SO.

Is this a problem on my side, or do other users have this too? I've tried enabling the insecure content, and that fixes my [other problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219573/css-broken-on-days-i-was-online) I've had.

Thanks in advance,

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713824/robuust' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Is it display all the time or only on some parts of SO. Maybe it due to an advertisement? I have reported a related problem here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208156/page-includes-script-from-unauthenticated-sources

Comment: Your issue seems to be resolved, however when I click my consecutive days - it's getting a shield and no CSS as I stated in the other problemm

Comment: @Robuust I opened my consecutive days thing in chrome, all seem fine. I guess it is from your side. Do you have any toolbars/extensions installed?

Comment: Could this be my profile picture? <img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/xVUAl.png?s=128&amp;g=1" alt="" class="logo"> I've uploaded this image via SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [HTTPS support on SO is still in an "alpha" state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites): it *mostly* works, but there are a lot of details that still need to be fixed before it's ready for prime time.

That said, there *shouldn't* normally be anything on SO that would cause the "shield" icon to appear; insecure images are not enough for that (although they do cause a warning triangle to appear over the padlock icon), since Chrome will allow them by default.  The shield only appears if Chrome has actually blocked some active content (e.g. JavaScript) from loading over an insecure HTTP connection.

The only situations I know of that would cause that on SE sites are:

- On [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) and other [MathJax-enabled sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax), the page currently [still attempts to load MathJax over HTTP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215450/ssl-breaks-tex-rendering).  (I have a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) that will work around this, although it doesn't get rid of the shield icon.)  However, SO does not use MathJax, so this can't be the problem there.
- Sometimes, [ads may try to load insecure content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208156/page-includes-script-from-unauthenticated-sources).  If you notice this happening, you should report it.

Anyway, when diagnosing issues like this, it helps a lot to know *what* script or other resource is being blocked.  To find that out, open *Tools → JavaScript Console* from your Chrome menu (while viewing the page where this happens) and look for messages that look something like this:

> [image: Screenshot of block content messages in Chrome console]

(Ps. Looks like I really should report that second blocked URL in the screenshot above.  It appears to have been fixed to use HTTPS on SO, but not on math.SE and some other SE sites.)

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Robuust: That's odd... SO does not normally load jQuery UI (and certainly not v1.10; SE is still stuck with jQuery v1.7).  Can you click the link on the right below the message, and show use the code that's actually trying to load it (and, in particular, whether it's SO's own code, something loaded over an ad network, or possibly something from an extension or user script that's messing with the page).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rKB1Yr3r

Comment: Ah, that's not very useful: it's just telling you that some script called jQuery.ajax() to actually load the URL. :-( You could try to find out what triggered it by adding a breakpoint (tip: prettify the code first by clicking the `{}` icon) and stepping through the page load until you find the bad call, but that can be a bit tricky if you haven't done it before.

Comment: @Robuust: ps. One think you could check is to open the page in Incognito mode with all extensions disabled (they normally are, unless you've checked the box that says "Allow in incognito mode") and see if the shield icon still appears. If it does, also note any ads on the page (maybe post a screenshot). You could also try looking in the Network tab in Developer Tools and seeing which scripts have been loaded from each site (especially the ad networks); that might help narrow down the suspects. Sorry if this all seems like scraping the barrel, though, since that's pretty much what it is.