# CSS for daily site access calendar on profile page fails to load over HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, ssl

Google Chrome:
Version 32.0.1700.107 m

This happens when displaying the profile and clicking on the number of visited days/consecutive.

.

[image: Layout bug]

Comment: Same version of Chrome here, on MacOS, but the Calendar looks completely different, with no bug.

Comment: Yep it's Windows 7 here.

Comment: I found out that this problem occurs when using a HTTPS connection to the site, as the script for the calendar is considered as unsafe by Chrome. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uOTZU.png

Comment: Aha! So *that's* what's causing [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219926/google-shield-on-so-insecure-content)!

Comment: This seems to have been fixed at some point.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in the AJAX response to the URL [`/users/daily-site-access/<uid>`](/users/daily-site-access/174699), which contains the following `<link>` tag:

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Note the hardcoded `http:` protocol, even if the page is being viewed over HTTPS.

Simply removing the `http:` to make the URL protocol-relative should fix this issue.  We're already using protocol-relative URLs to load jQuery itself, so doing the same for the CSS should not be a problem.

**Edit:** Since this hasn't been properly fixed yet, I've included a client-side fix for this issue in [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) 1.8.  Note that the fix won't prevent the "shield" icon from appearing when the calendar is first loaded, but it does reload the style sheet over HTTPS after the initial request over HTTP fails.